# issuing dos commands from inside ruby on rails controller in the same dos session

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, session, command-line, dos

**Here is my scenario**.
I have a ajax call in my web site to find the elevation at particular point. Once this point comes into an action of a controller in Ruby on rails, I have to use python on command line to find the elevation.

The following sequence of commands in DOS does that for me.

1. python (starts a python session)
2. import arcpy (takes a lot of time)
3. function call (very fast).

Now if I put this into a script and run it, I do get the result, but its very slow, because the 'import' step takes a lot of time. But the actual function takes less than a second.

As all this is suppose to happen behind an Ajax call on ror web site, such a large delay is unacceptable.

**Question:**
Is it possible for me in  Ror to open a 'command line session' when the application loads and issue the first two commands, and then use this session every time a request comes in a controller's action, and issue the third command, and return its output?
If yes can someone please post some samples?

Thanks
Shaunak

Comment: I did not know that RoR could run under DOS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are proposing could be possible if Rails was friendlier about forked processes.  A cleaner and better solution would be to write a python daemon that you could query so that you don't incur the startup penalty.  (This could be a web-service or a daemon you communicate with standard network sockets or whatever).